# VS2015: non accurate fread after a fseek operation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fread, fseek

While moving a project from vs2008 to vs2015 I fall into what looks like to be a bug in the VS2015 libc.
The issue is that after a fseek operation to position X, the fread reads data starting at X+10.

No error are raised, the ftell calls after the fseek operation returns the attended position, but the fread does not start at the attended position. Moreover, it depends on the previous fseek/fread operation.

This issue is not present when running with VS2008 (32 or 64bits), and is present when running with VS2015 (32 or 64bits).

Thanks by advance for any ideas !!

The binary file is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6wrf5dnr5o59ir8/AACVb68vKs8cCPW2bKBTYHmWa?dl=0).
The sample code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

bool foo(FILE *f, unsigned char *buffer, int seek_to, int read_bytes)
{
    size_t res = 0;
    std::cout << "\tSeek to " << seek_to << std::endl;
    // issue present if using fseek or _fseeki64
    if (fseek(f, seek_to, SEEK_SET) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\tFAILED" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "\tRead " << read_bytes << " bytes" << std::endl;
    if ((res = fread(buffer, 1, read_bytes, f)) != read_bytes)
    {
        std::cout << "\tFAILED, " << res << "bytes readen" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
return true;
}

// issue is present in 32 and 64bits of VS2015 update 3
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // open the AVC binary file
    FILE *favc = fopen(argv[1], "rb");    
    // big buffer
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[1024*1024];
    // step 1, seek and read
    std::cout << "Step 1" << std::endl;
    foo(favc, buffer, 35026374, 7730);
    std::cout << "Step 2" << std::endl;
    foo(favc, buffer, 35030470, 8192);
    // failing reading, buffer should start with 00 00 00 01 09
    std::cout << "Step 3 - where all failed" << std::endl;
    foo(favc, buffer, 35034577, 16428);
    std::cout << "Buffer: '";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned int)buffer[i];
    std::cout << "'" << std::endl;
    unsigned int v = *((unsigned int*)(buffer+1));
    if (v != 0x09010000) std::cout << "ISSUE DETECTED" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that:
- this is also present if using fread_s/fopen_s or _open/_lseek/_read function

Comment: Issue is not present if using _open, _read and _lseek. So much looking as a buffering error in fopen on vs2015

Comment: Also present in VS2017....

Comment: Adjusting the buffer size with setvbuf also change the issue location. Seems really to be a bug with buffering.

Comment: Issue is not present when runned on windows 10... :(

Comment: Issue located when building with the SDK 8.1
Follow here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c4d27db-1128-4803-951b-fef515455a03/vs2015-non-accurate-fseekfread-operation?forum=msbuild&prof=required

Comment: I've added a `rewind` before the `fseek` and it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is confirmed as a bug with the VC Redist 2015 on SDK8.1 target.
See bugtracking here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3133357

And MSDN forum status: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c4d27db-1128-4803-951b-fef515455a03/vs2015-non-accurate-fseekfread-operation?forum=msbuild&prof=required

Workaround are:
- do not use fopen/fread/fseek function, prefere WIN32 API CreateFile/...
- target Windows 10 (not 7 with SDK8.1)